# ASP.Net MVC - redirecting to route gives Redirect Loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

This is probably one of those easy questions..  I'm trying to redirect the user after they've successfully authenticated, or return them back to the login page. But the Success page is on a different route and I can't get the redirection to work..

Here are my routes in Globals.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute( _
    "Default", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Login", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )
routes.MapRoute( _
    "Stuff", _
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
    New With {.controller = "Stuff", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )
```

I've got 2 Controllers: `LoginController.vb` and `StuffController.vb`.  The `Views/Login/Index.aspx` file contains a simple form with the code:

```
<form method="post" action="/Login/Authenticate">
```

The `LoginController` contains the following code:

```
Function Authenticate() As RedirectToRouteResult
    ' authentication code commented out  ;o)

    Return RedirectToRoute("Stuff")
End Function
```

And the StuffController contains the following:

```
Function Index()
    ' show stuff..

    Return View()    ' return /Views/Stuff/Index.aspx
End Function
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Function Authenticate()
- Function Authenticate() As ActionResult()
- Function Authenticate() As RedirectToRouteResult()

all of which cause a Redirect Loop timeout in the browser. What am I missing?!

Comment: Great question, I was having the same problem!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be that your Stuff route has exactly the same form as the default one, so when you call

```
Return RedirectToRoute("Stuff");
```

the resulting url has the form: {controller}/{action}/{id}, e.g. Login/Authenticate again, since you are inside Login-controller's Authenticate action.

Try to

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Stuff");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You're correct. I removed the 'Stuff' Route, and used the RedirectToAction("[View]", "[Controller]") and it works - thanks for your help  :o)

Comment: Oh, and I needed to change the Return Type of the Authenticate Function to "ActionResult" too  :o)

Answer (score 11):

Correct answer is good, but:

- what if you ever want to change the controller/action name from Staff/Index to something else?

-then you will need to change the values not only in global.asax, but also in all the places where you used the technique.

My suggestion:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Stuff", (RouteTable.Routes["Stuff"] as Route).Defaults);
```

Now, in this case, you don't pass the names of controller/action which is Stuff/Index accordingly. This will let you manage changes easily.

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see where you are setting the authentication cookie or marking the user as having been authenticated in any way.  Is that in the code that you have omitted?

Comment: Yes, I may be wrong but I didn't think I'd need any authentication code as all I'm really trying to do here is 'jump' Controllers - from the LoginController to the StuffController

Comment: If you don't set the auth. cookie, provided your action methods are decorated with the [Authorize] attribute, then you will be redirected back to your login url again.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the [Authorize] attribute. Truth is when I was trying to get this working I hadn't written the authorisation code so I hadn't decorated any Action Methods with [Authorize] - I was just getting the 'flow' right to start with  :o)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
routes.MapRoute( _    
"Stuff", _
"",_  
New With {.controller = "Stuff", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _    
)
```